# How to make actionscript 2 interpret code as plain text?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, textinput, plaintext

I'm trying to make a flash-based activity where the end-user will type in some Java as a writing exercise, and when it's done, they will hit enter and flash will check to see if they typed correctly.

The problem comes where I am writing the actionscript. When I test the movie, flash throws out lots of errors because it thinks the Java I typed in the input text box is just poorly formatted code. The code I am using has worked in the past for simple things like typing a name, or a number, but with the code-type input, it breaks. I know there are tags in HTML to display code as text, but I can't find anything about how to do this within actionscript 2. Here's what I have:

```
keyListener = new Object();
keyListener.onKeyDown = function() {
if(Key.getCode() == Key.ENTER){
if(allthecode.text == "
    // Import the required API classes.
    import java.util.Scanner;
 
    public class ShowByte 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    // Create the scanner.
    Scanner GetByte = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Obtain a byte value.
    System.out.print("Type any number: ");
    byte MyByte = GetByte.nextByte();

    // Display the value on screen.
    System.out.println("The value of MyByte is: " + MyByte);
    }
    }
    ") {gotoAndPlay(150);
        }
    }
};
Key.addListener(keyListener);
```

EDIT:Lee figured out it was that the code was on multiple lines. As soon as I placed everything within '   ' marks and scrunched everything up to a single line, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think youre getting errors because of the way you have formatted your string - you have " surrounding string but also within it - flash gets confused. Use either " or ' to surround string and then other type within string. eg:

```
if (allthecode.text == '
    // Import the required API classes.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShowByte 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
// Create the scanner.
Scanner GetByte = new Scanner(System.in);

// Obtain a byte value.
System.out.print("Type any number: ");
byte MyByte = GetByte.nextByte();

// Display the value on screen.
System.out.println("The value of MyByte is: " + MyByte);
}
}
') {gotoAndPlay(150);
```

Or post the error message you get and prove me wrong ;)

Comment: notice how stackExchange itself formats my string differently to yours - your code has syntax higlighting within the inner strings; mine doesnt.

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this. I tried the idea, and while it did format the code differently (seems like a good sign!) it still threw out the errors...
1.Line4: String literal was not properly terminated  
2.Line6: ')' expected  
3.Line7: Syntax error.  
4.Line8: Attribute used outside class.  
5.Line10:Syntax error.  
6.Line13:The class or interface 'java.util.Scanner' could not be loaded.  
7.Line17: Syntax error.  
8.Line22: Unexpected '}' encountered  
9.Line23:string literal was not properly terminated.  

So... kind of a mess. :-/

Comment: your {} aren't balanced - add another "}" after "gotoAndPlay(150);"

Comment: doh! you dont need an extra } - i miscounted i think. its probably because your string spans multiple lines. i dont use AS2 anymore so i may be wrong.

Comment: Huh. It's always the simple answers in the end. The problem was having multiple lines. I'm used to HTML where usually multiple lines in the text editor make no difference. Thank you so much!